# Sigfox Callback CustomValue's issue Sending NULL instead of wanted values

Tags: communication, wireless, data-transfer, sigfox

I'm working on a project, and I want to use a Sigfox callback to send some data.
But when I want separate my payload as I coded it, all my values on Callback are NULL.

This is my Callback, and this is what the Callback send :[image]

[image]

My full custom payload is

```
tempAir::int:10: tempGnd::int:10 wetAir::uint:10 wetGnd::uint:10 alti::int:8 magX::uint:10 magY::uint:10 MagZ::uint:10
```

and the message I send by captors is like : `388eb7c406412e8e33806b21`.

If I change my payload by things like

```
tempAir::int:8: tempGnd::int:8 wetAir::uint:8 wetGnd::uint:8 alti::int:8 magX::uint:8 magY::uint:8 MagZ::uint:8
```

or

```
tempAir::int:10: tempGnd::int:10 wetAir::uint:10 wetGnd::uint:8 alti::int:8 magX::uint:8 magY::uint:8 MagZ::uint:8
```

callback works properly. But the values decoded are obviously wrong because this is not the way I custom my payload.

I don't find the difference between those custom payloads, and why others payload works and my doesn't. And it's not a number of bit's issue as I already saw on previous posts, because I want to read 78 bits and my message contains at least 80 bits.

I have spent 10 hours trying to solve this but I really don't understand why my custom payload doesn't work. If someone have the solution, I'm buying!